# Variable changing unseen

Tags: c++, variables

I'm (trying to) write a  program that's a sort of simplified neural net, where offby is my function to measure how close to the goal value the neural net gets on this iteration. It seems to be working completely fine except for the fact that (seemingly randomly) it sometimes assigns a negative value to offby.

The only block of code where offby can change is (aside from setting it back to 0 at the start of every iteration):

```
offby = offby + std::abs((sigmoid(outcome[k]) - goal));
```

After that bit of code I have it output the offby value, and it's working fine. Then I have the bit of code below (where it changes the value of one of the connections in the net).

```
std::cout << "Offby is before 5: " << offby << "\n";
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> which_unit(0, unitsinlayer3);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> which_connection(0, unitsinlayer4);
one = which_unit(rng);
two = which_connection(rng);
thirdtofourth[one][two] = +mutateby;
std::cout << "Offby is after 5: " << offby << "\n";
```

At "offby is before 5" it still outputs the correct value, then at "offby is after 5" it sometimes outputs a negative value. There is literally no other code in between, the only reason I've even figured out it's this part of the code that assigns a negative value somehow is through having it output offby at practically every bit of code and seeing where it changes.

Now I might be missing something completely obvious, but how come changing these other variables might change my offby value?

In case this is relevant, mutateby is assigned as follows (earlier in the code)

```
std::normal_distribution<double> mutation(0, 0.1);
double mutateby = mutation(rng);
```

Just as an example, this just happened when I ran the program:

Offby is before 5: 0.000000

Offby is after 5: -0.056328

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Turns out that it changes specifically in this line:

```
thirdtofourth[one][two] = +mutateby;
```

Comment: You could debug your code and check at which point offby changes its value. I think that there is a pointer or reference to offby.

Comment: `which_unit(rng)` will produce a value between `0` and `unitsinlayer3` *inclusive*.    Similarly for `which_connection`.  This means the dimensions of `thirdoffourth` must be at least at least `[unitsinlayer3 + 1][unitsinlayer4+1]`.    Note the plus ones.   If the actual dimension are loss than that, `thirdtofourth[one][two] = +mutateby` writes past the end of the array i.e. undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter That seems to have solved it indeed. I really need to wrap my head around the 0-1 mistakes. Thanks, this had me stuck for quite a while.